# summary of quantile regression with rqpd does not return standard errors

Tags: r, quantile-regression

I am using rqpd package in R to have a quantile regression with fixed effects (quantreg package does not support quantile regressions with fixed effects) as follow:

```
reg_q1 <- rqpd::rqpd(NoneHousingExpense ~ totalIncome + treatmentMonthly +
                 as.factor(year) + HHsize_eq| Address,
               panel(method = "pfe", taus = seq(0.02,0.98,0.02), tauw = rep(1/49,49)),
               data = adj_df1, weights = adj_df1$rWeight)
```

and I was using `summary(reg_q1)$coefficients` to get coefficients and standard errors. It was working perfectly a year ago, but I am back to my code after a year and the summary function returns only a character like this:

```
             Length  Class      Mode   
coefficients     246 -none-     numeric
residuals    1313054 -none-     numeric
coef             246 -none-     numeric
X                  1 matrix.csr S4     
Z                  1 matrix.csr S4     
y              26797 -none-     numeric
ids            26797 -none-     numeric
panel              6 -none-     list   
control            7 -none-     list   
formula            3 formula    call   
call               5 -none-     call   
rank               1 -none-     numeric
```

Do you know how I can get the standard errors from it? Has the package been changed recently in terms of outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. Instead of using summary(reg_q1), try using rqpd::summary.rqpd(reg_q1). This solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is here:

```
summary.rqpd(reg_q1)
```